# How to iterate throught a list of 2000 records and pick three top frequent repeated records?

Tags: c#, linq

SO.
I have a list of 2k+ name records. I want to find the top three frequent repeated names in my list. So far I figured out how to get the `First()` one with the following:

```
var mostPopular = likes.GroupBy(i => i.name).OrderByDescending(grp => grp.Count()).Select(grp => grp.Key).First();
```

How can I get the other two? Help please.

Comment: Use `Take(3)` instead of `First`. It will return `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>>`, use `SelectMany` to flatten to a single collection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `Take` function.

```
var mostPopular = likes.GroupBy(i => i.name)
.OrderByDescending(grp => grp.Count())
.Select(grp => grp.Key)
.Take(3);
```

Comment: How can I use this variable then? is it like `string name1 = mostpopular.First()`

Comment: You could do that or use for loop or use .Skip function to get 2nd and 3rd. mostPopular.Skip(1).First(); //to get second and use .Skip(2).First() to get the 3rd item.